# Uninstalled Expo app from iOS simulator, how can I reinstall it?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

So I uninstalled my Expo iOS app and now can't install it by running `yarn start` , then pressing i for iOS. When I try, I get:

CommandError: No development build (com.inkwell.inkwell) for this project is installed. Please make and install a development build on the device first.
Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/development/build/

How can I install it?

Comment: Are you using Expo Go or custom Expo Dev Client?

Comment: Expo Dev Client

Comment: A simple solution is downloading.IPA file of Expo Dev Client form EAS servers and install directly to Simulator

Comment: Install, IPA requires Apple Developer Program Account.

Comment: Full process here - https://youtu.be/id0Im72UN6w